# encryption using java in web automation using webdriver

Tags: java, encryption, automation, webdriver

I am in search for an Idea to encrypt the password (login password) and decrypt before typing.

Has anyone done such a thing?

I know that we have to be sure that encryption logic shouldn't be visible to users but I'm not sure how exactly to hide/secure it?

Comment: could you explain what you mean by 'decrypt before typing'?

Comment: perhaps some javascript and java encryption function. The idea is to create the key in java, store it in session and then pass it to the javascript encryption function. Then when the server receives the post it should be able to take back the key from the session and decrypt the password

Comment: @lynks : Sure. I need to type the password into the page (decrypted password) but I do not want the password to be available anywhere in its real form (like in an excelsheet or something). I want the code to internally decrypt the password (taking encrypted string from the excelsheet) and type on the password field of the login page.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, any approach you take that is totally automated will be duplicatable by a user that can access the java program. All the ingredients they need to decrypt the password will be present in the program. If they are able to run the program, they can also just use it 'blindly' to decrypt the password for them.

However, you can try to make it difficult for a person who gains access to your filesystem to yield the unencrypted password.

You will be encrypting your password under some key `K`, using say AES-128.

Your challenge is then to make `K` hard to come by, so make it something that your program has to calculate every time. Then an attacker has to copy those calculations in order to yield the key, this would usually mean forcing them to reverse engineer the program - unless, as I say, they are able to simply *run* the program.

You could also make it so that the calculation relies on some remote value, stored on a webserver or such.

There are many approaches, but you're not going to do better than security-through-obscurity. It will never actually be *secure* as such. Just make something up :P